# jsreport.Local and remote SQL Server repository

Tags: jsreport

In the latest version of jsreport.Local and jsreport.Binary, how can i configure to use a remote templates repository like SQL Server?

On the prior versions i could change the **prod.config.json** file and put the configurations like

```
"connectionString": {
    "name": "mssql",
    "user": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "server": "MyServer",
    "database": "dbName",
    "options": {
      "encrypt": true
    }
  }
```

there after install **jsreport-mssql-store** package.
At now, i found a type

```
jsreport.Types.ConnectionStringConfiguration
```

that accept a property called Name, but only this.

Answer (score 0):

The custom extensions like `jsreport-mssql-store` are not part of the default jsreport executable which is embedded in the `jsreport.Local`. To get it running you need to do the following steps.

1. Create folder `jsreport` in your project
2. Make sure the whole folder is being copied to the output directory. This can be done using wildcard in the `csproj` file.
3. Run `npm install jsreport-mssql-store` in the `jsreport` folder
4. Create `dev.config.json` there

```
{
    "connectionString": {
      "name": "mssql",
      "user": "jsreport",
      "password": "password",
      "server": "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS",
      "database": "jsreport"
    },
    "discover":  true
}
```

Now you can use `jsreport.Local` the same way as described in docs. However personally I would probably rather use standalone instance in this complex case and use just `jsreport.Client` to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, if i update by npm my old jsreport files that was included/installed by the deprecated jsreport.Embedded packate and update the jsreport.Local to the newest version this must work correctly? Or by other words, i will do the manualy work jsreport.Binary, right?

Comment: You should probably start from scratch with `jsreport.Local` and `jsreport.Binary` and use the steps I described. However if things works for you, you can also keep using `jsreport.Embedded`.